# Google Analytics Content Experiment showing no visitors

Tags: url, parameters, google-analytics, analytics, google-experiments

I've got a content experiment running in Google Analytics and it isn't showing any visitors.  The code is validating correctly and appears to be functioning correctly if I test it.

I've used parameterised versions of the same page (?v=1, ?v=2, ...) for the different variations.

It also may be because the experiment is on a search page which receives a parameter of what is being searched on in the URL.

Anyone got any experience with these problems yet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to take a few hours for my data to start showing up. So depending on how impatient you are it may just take more time.

I also had a problem since I had **Enable Demographics and Interest Reports** turned on ([Question that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003286/google-analytics-content-experiment-without-redirect-getting-no-visitors))