# google analytics content experiment without redirect getting no visitors

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-experiments

I have implemented a GA experiment with no redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">_udn = 'example.com'; _uhash='off';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=ExperimentID"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'AccountID']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowHash', false]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I don't seem to get any visits.
The instructions I followed are here [experiments-client-side](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side)

I have followed the accepted answer at this  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537051/why-arent-results-from-google-analytics-content-experiments-showing)

Google still does not seem to be receiving my experiment visits.

I am wondering if it has something to do with using **stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js** instead of **ga.js**

Answer (score 0):

Change the ga.src to ga.js experiments don't seem to work with stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
```

was changed to

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

This solution is not optimal since it stops me from getting demographic data but I am at least getting experiment data now.

Comment: Maybe I just didn't give it enough time. It is possible that I need to give it more time. Anyone else have any experience with how long it takes?