# Does the DoubleClick Google Analytics integration support content experiments?

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

Does anyone know if the DoubleClick google analytics integration (dc.js) supports Google Content Experiments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately [it doesn't as of now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003286/google-analytics-content-experiment-without-redirect-getting-no-visitors). I hear GA team is revamping the whole experimenting platform though, so hopefully soon.

I suggest using other optimization tools like [Visual Website Optimizer](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/) or [Optimizely](https://www.optimizely.com/), they are far more advanced and easier to use.